# Qt. Win10. Вывод в консоль в приложении с GUI

Tags: qt, qt5.15

При работе с консольным приложением Qt вывод в консоль происходит (std::cout).
При при работе с GUI приложением вывода в консоль не происходит, а надо.

Вопрос: почему?

Comment: В линуксе подобных проблем нет.

Comment: в QtCreator, во вкладке "Вывод приложения", требуемый вывод есть

Comment: а где консоль у GUI app? или вам надо чтобы она появилась? это можно

Comment: при запуске из консоли

Comment: в windows наличие консоли определяется тем как собрана программа, в линукс консоль всегда есть, но она может быть скрыта

Comment: и? вывод в консоль нужен

Comment: Установил параметр "Запускать в терминале" - "Включено"  - вывода в него (терминал) тоже нет

Comment: добавьте в проект `LIBS += "-SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE"`

Comment: достаточно добавить в проект `CONFIG += console`

Comment: оба варианта не помогают

Comment: я собираю для Qt6 VS2022, в qt creator, работает, добавил `CONFIG += console` в analogclock

Comment: я на mingw сижу

Comment: сделал `CONFIG += console` для Qt6.2.4 MinGW 11.2 - есть вывод в консоль

Comment: Прошу прощения. CONFIG += console действительно помогает! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Pavel Gridin!
Добавление CONFIG += console решает вопрос